# Unity and Vuforia virtual button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm new into Unity + Vuforia, I'm developing an AR app with virtual buttons.
I have seen lots of videos on youtube and they all use the same method working with Virtual Buttons.
However, the `IVirtualButtonEventHandler` seems deprecated, and I haven't seen any alternative sample code for it.

[image: Deprecated warning]

Please help
Thanks

Comment: It may help if you take a look at the Virtual Button Samples. https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples

Answer (score 1):

It seems they have deprecated the IVirtualButtonEventHandler interface in version 9. Just remove the interface from your script and add the handlers individually with the new methods: RegisterOnButtonPressed and RegisterOnButtonReleased. Example:

```
void Start()
{
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonPressed(OnButtonPressed);
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonReleased(OnButtonReleased);
}

public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
{
    print("*** button Pressed " + vb.VirtualButtonName);
}

public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
{
    print("*** button Released " + vb.VirtualButtonName);
}
```